# Two-body problem in friction

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction

When a block is placed on a slab having coeff. of friction u which is on a frictionless horizontal surface.
Suppose if we apply a force F on upper block which is lesser than the value of limiting friction then the static friction should be equal to applied external force and the net acceleration should be zero but both block will move with acceleration F/(M+m). Where am I wrong please explain.
For referance I'm uploading a photo with an example.

[image]